# R replace nested loop with a more efficient way of going over 2 dataframes

Tags: r, nested-loops, lapply

I want to match state and district code between 2 dataframes and thus retrieve the production and yield of crop for the first dataframe.

Can somebody please help me in replacing the nested loop below for a more efficient way:

```
for (i in 1:length(og_county2$State)){
  for (j in 1:length(km2$State)){    
      if (is.na(og_county2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - ACRES HARVESTED`[i]) == "TRUE" & (as.character(og_county2$State[i]) == as.character(km2$State[j])) & (as.character(og_county2$District.code[i]) == as.character(km2$Ag.District.Code[j]))& km2$County[j] =="OTHER (COMBINED) COUNTIES"){

        og_county2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - ACRES HARVESTED`[i] = km2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - ACRES HARVESTED`[j]
      }
    if (is.na(og_county2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - PRODUCTION, MEASURED IN BU`[i]) == "TRUE" & (as.character(og_county2$State[i]) == as.character(km2$State[j])) & (as.character(og_county2$District.code[i]) == as.character(km2$Ag.District.Code[j]))& km2$County[j] =="OTHER (COMBINED) COUNTIES"){

      og_county2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - PRODUCTION, MEASURED IN BU`[i] = km2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - PRODUCTION, MEASURED IN BU`[j]
    }
    if (is.na(og_county2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - YIELD, MEASURED IN BU / ACRE`[i]) == "TRUE" & (as.character(og_county2$State[i]) == as.character(km2$State[j])) & (as.character(og_county2$District.code[i]) == as.character(km2$Ag.District.Code[j]))& km2$County[j] =="OTHER (COMBINED) COUNTIES"){

      og_county2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - YIELD, MEASURED IN BU / ACRE`[i] = km2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - YIELD, MEASURED IN BU / ACRE`[j]
    }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example including example input data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 'merge()' function: http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-in-r-merge-in-r/

Comment: merge(og_county2[is.na(og_county2$`Value.CORN, GRAIN - ACRES HARVESTED`[i]) == "TRUE",], km2[km2$County[j] =="OTHER (COMBINED) COUNTIES",], by.x =c( "State","District.code"), 
             by.y =c("State",Ag.District.Code), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)

Comment: Thank you for replying. So, something like above I guess. I was also seeing people use apply function and wasn't sure how to do that.

Comment: I tried below: 

res <- merge(og_county2[is.na(og_county2$"Value.CORN, GRAIN - ACRES HARVESTED") == "TRUE",], km2[km2$County =="OTHER (COMBINED) COUNTIES",], by.x =c( "State","District.code"), by.y =c("State","Ag.District.Code"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)

but it didn't give me satisfactory result because now, I have columns from both the dataframes and also the values are not filled for the column "Value.CORN, GRAIN - ACRES HARVESTED" in OG_County2

Comment: i tried below but that gives me "NA" columns:

```
res <- left_join(og_county2[is.na(og_county2$"Value.CORN, GRAIN - ACRES HARVESTED") == "TRUE",], km2[km2$County =="OTHER (COMBINED) COUNTIES",], by.x =c( "State","District.code"), by.y =c("State","Ag.District.Code")) 
```